# In Swift, how to ivalidate NSTimer in AppDelegate when application going background?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, nstimer, appdelegate

I need to translate my iOS application from obj-c to swift. I have a `NStimer` in `ViewController` that loads metadata from shoutcast every 30 seconds, but when application resign active it stops, when enter foreground it runs again.

Edit: OK. Problem solved! I added two observers in viewDidLoad with name `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`, like below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSLog("System Version is \(UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion)");
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.runTimer()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "invalidateTimer", name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "runTimer", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}
```

and I made two functions. First one for run timer:

```
func runTimer(){
    loadMetadata()
    myTimer.invalidate()
    NSLog("timer run");
    myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(30.0, target: self, selector: "loadMetadata", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    let mainLoop = NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop()
    mainLoop.addTimer(myTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
}
```

and second to stop it:

```
func invalidateTimer(){
    myTimer.invalidate()
    NSLog("timer invalidated %u", myTimer);
}
```

I hope this can help someone. :)

Comment: the objC is broken already -- what is it do you would even like to do

Comment: objC ins't broken, it works. I showed only code for timer, without method `loadMetadata` what is selector for timer, and without the rest of my project. :)

Comment: Problem solved! Look at the bottom of first post. :)

Comment: the code is broken - and I don't mean there is stuff missing or that it won't compile - anyways, good luck

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the appropriate system for your task: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56

> Apps that need to check for new content periodically can ask the
>   system to wake them up so that they can initiate a fetch operation for
>   that content. To support this mode, enable the Background fetch option
>   from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your
>   Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the
>   UIBackgroundModes key with the fetch value in your app’s Info.plist
>   file.)...
>
> When a good opportunity arises, the system wakes or launches your app
>   into the background and calls the app delegate’s
>   `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` method. Use that method
>   to check for new content and initiate a download operation if content
>   is available.